Gitlab CI has empty variable defined in same CI file
I’m running this minimal .gitlab-ci.yml script on gitlab.com with default shared runners:
variables:
  VAR: Value

job:
  only:
    - main

  run:
  - name: test
    script: echo VAR=$VAR

This is the output
steps:
    - name: test
      script: echo VAR=$VAR
VAR=

What the hell is going on? How do I actually get the value of my variable? This seems to be directly contradicting the docs on variables.
Note that setting CI_DEBUG_TRACE: true shows
CI_RUNNER_VERSION=17.4.0~pre.110.g27400594
and
++ export VAR=Value
++ VAR=Value

So it seems to be the script that is unable to access/inherit the environment rather than the variables being ignored.
Running script: env confirms this:
steps:
    - name: test
      script: env
PWD=/builds
SHLVL=0
PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env


I’ve looked for this issue but all potential dupes I’ve found are misses: this isn’t the same as having that empty variables in the environment section, or protected variables, or loading variables from source, etc.

I think the issue here is not with the variables but with the run: syntax which is, as of writing, still marked as “Experiment” and “not ready for production use”. I just tested the same with the usual single script syntax, and the variables worked as expected:
variables:
  VAR: Value

job:
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - echo VAR=$VAR

And in the output I see:
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ echo VAR=$VAR
VAR=Value
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
Job succeeded


Weird… the run with steps syntax seems definitely valid and documented, and the script code is executed. But it seems to behave differently

looks like yes, and maybe because it still marked as Experiment ...

unfortunately I can't check that new syntax - me gitlab too old for it
